# Two model java mapped with one to many mapping but data not mapped with required colomns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have used one to many relationship between two models with join colomn(crnumber) but crnumber colomn data updated with id colomn data from Parent table . Two mapping models pasted in below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CREFFORTSTABLE")
public class CREffortDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
     private String crNumber;
     private String description;
     private int totalPlannedHours;
     private int totalActualHours;


     @OneToMany ( mappedBy = "cREffortDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )

     private List<TaskData> taskData = new ArrayList<TaskData>();
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRTASKDATA")
public class TaskData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
     //private String crNumber;
    private String task;
    private String weekNumber;
    private String plannedHours;
    private String actualHours;
    @Transient 
    private Integer remove; 

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
     @JoinColumn(name = "crNumber", nullable = false)

    private CREffortDetails cREffortDetails;
```

Out put should be
**CREFFORTSTABLE** 
id crnumber description totalplannedhours totalactualhours
1   CH001234  0                  10         10

**CRTASKDATA** 
id task weeknumber plannedhours actualhours    crnumber
1   test w1              2        2             CH001234

Comment: Please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more ? Also, could you share the code that you use to fetch the data like the repository layer. Also sample data and expected data could also be helpful.